Как сделать так, чтобы записи выводились построчно, а не множились на столбцы
При запросе :
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT DATE, amount, 'bank' AS 'type' FROM bank_transactions) AS bank, (SELECT DATE, amount, 'cash' AS 'type' FROM cashbox_transactions) AS cash)

появляются одинаковые столбики и значения повторяются по 3 раза, как этого избежать. Пробовала писать DISTINCT перед *, но не помогло избежать проблемы


Вероятно, вам нужен UNION.

SELECT DATE, amount, 'bank' AS 'type' FROM bank_transactions UNION SELECT DATE, amount, 'cash' AS 'type' FROM cashbox_transactions - так попробуйте

благодарю, при помощи union получилось сделать так, как нужно. не подскажете, а при помощи вложенных запросов можно как-то к такому же результату прийти?

MySQL
-- Создать таблицы bank_transactions и cashbox_transactions
CREATE TABLE bank_transactions (      
  DATE DATETIME,
  amount DECIMAL(10,1)
);

CREATE TABLE cashbox_transactions (
  DATE DATETIME,
  amount DECIMAL(10,1)
);

-- Добавить данные
INSERT INTO bank_transactions VALUES ('2017-02-14 12:12:02', 1400.5),
('2017-02-03 15:43:18', 3000.0),
('2017-02-01 11:35:17', 560.0);

INSERT INTO cashbox_transactions VALUES ('2017-02-04 10:12:09', 74.0),
('2017-02-10 22:12:04', 871.0),
('2017-02-16 09:00:30', 1000.0);

-- Выбрать данные
SELECT DATE, amount, 'bank' AS 'type'           -- Выбрать столбцы DATE, amount и столбец заполненный текстовым значением 'bank' назвать type
FROM bank_transactions                          -- Из таблицы bank_transactions 
UNION                                           -- соединить с запросом
SELECT DATE, amount, 'cash' AS 'type'           -- Выбрать столбцы DATE, amount и столбец заполненный текстовым значением 'cash' назвать type
FROM cashbox_transactions;                      -- Из таблицы cashbox_transactions 


А зачем комментарии убрали?
